# how many max parameters junit perameterized test can handle?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, parameterized

I have total `2799030` parameters stored in `Iterable<Object[]>` and I was expecting `junit` to build/start these many tests. but it just hangs right after loading all parameters in `Iterable<Object[]>` - see screen shot below:

[image: hang here]

It works fine with small number of parameters (5000-10000). I also tried running with higher JVM memory (`-Xms1024M -Xmx4096M`)

**Update:** I also tried running from CLI instead of IDE, from error below it seems like I should run with more memory or change my design to run in small batches. - thoughts?

```
There was 1 failure:
1) initializationError(test.TestBuilder$buildTestSuites)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.specificToStringHeader(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Executable.sharedToString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.toString(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.internal.MethodSorter$2.compare(MethodSorter.java:33)
        at org.junit.internal.MethodSorter$2.compare(MethodSorter.java:28)
        at org.junit.internal.MethodSorter$1.compare(MethodSorter.java:20)
        at org.junit.internal.MethodSorter$1.compare(MethodSorter.java:14)
        at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.internal.MethodSorter.getDeclaredMethods(MethodSorter.java:56)
        at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.scanAnnotatedMembers(TestClass.java:65)
        at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.createTestClass(ParentRunner.java:88)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:83)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
        at org.junit.runners.parameterized.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.parameterized.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParametersFactory.createRunnerForTestWithParameters(BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParametersFactory.java:16)
        at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.createRunnersForParameters(Parameterized.java:313)
        at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.<init>(Parameterized.java:248)
        at pps.test.Parallelized.<init>(Parallelized.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the designer execution test

For example:

- make 10 methods in your class test.
- each method run 10000 items.
- run in parallel test.
- find or do items when consumed.

if you not can't do this.
you need more memory for make your test,